# A detail in the proof of Schur's lemma: the closures of the $\mathcal{Ker}$ and $\mathcal{Im}$ of the intertwiner

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, mp.mathematical-physics, unbounded-operators

$\renewcommand\Im{\operatorname{\mathcal{Im}}}\newcommand\Ker{\operatorname{\mathcal{Ker}}}$I was sure that this is a trivial question and placed it on Math Stackexchange
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136830/a-detail-in-the-proof-of-schurs-lemma-the-closures-of-the-cal-ker-and-cal

Surprisingly, no one answered it there. So I am elevating it to MathOverflow.

---

Consider two irreducibles of a topological group $G$, acting in respective Hilbert spaces $\mathbb V$ and $\mathbb V'$.

Schur's lemma says:

An intertwiner $M : \mathbb V\longrightarrow\mathbb V'$ of two irreducibles of a group is either zero or isomorphism.

To prove it, we first show that both $\Im M$ and $\Ker M$ are invariant subspaces.  Then two observations are made.

**Observation 1.** For the invariance of $\Im M$ to agree with the irreducibility, $\Im M$ must coincide either with the space $\mathbb V'$ or with its zero subspace $\{\smash{\vec0}'\}$.

**Observation 2.** For the invariance of $\Ker M$ to agree with the irreducibility, $\Ker M$ must coincide either with the space $\mathbb V$ or with its zero subspace $\{\vec0\}$.

Summing up these observations, we conclude that $M$ is either zero or bijective and therefore invertible.

Now, my **question**. Is it really true that $\Im M$ itself must coincide either with $\mathbb V'$ or $\{\smash{\vec0}'\}$? Or is it rather the *closure* of $\Im M$ that must satisfy this requirement?  I am enquiring, because a representation is always defined in a Hilbert space or in a *closed* thereof.

The same question about $\Ker M$. Should we prove that it is actually its *closure* that is invariant?

If it is the closures of $\Im M$ and $\Ker M$ whose invariance needs to be proven, do we have to impose additional requirements on the representations and/or on the intertwiner $M$ (say, boundedness)?

Comment: As you suspect, I believe the statement should be about a *continuous* intertwiner, whose image and kernel are both closed.  Could you point to where you have seen the theorem stated without this condition?

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for this valuable comment. I see that I should change "group" to "topological group", and "intertwiner" to "continuous intertwiner". You enquired where I saw the lemma without the condition of continuity. The answer is simple: in ANY book on quantum mechanics. Few physicists know topology, and certainly none of them cares about the difference between the algebraic and topological irreducibility. To a physicist, the irreducibility implies the lack of invariant proper subspaces. Saying " invariant *closed* proper subspaces" is beyond the level of rigor attained in physics books

Comment: Valuable explanation (which I still have to digest) is kindly provided by Pedro Lauridsen Ribeiro in the comments to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4136830/a-detail-in-the-proof-of-schurs-lemma-the-closures-of-the-cal-ker-and-cal

Comment: If you assume $M$ to be continuous, then $\mathcal{Ker}M$ is closed, but $\mathcal{Im}M$ need not be closed, and it could be a nontrivial proper non-closed $G$-invariant subspace. For representations of $C^*$-algebras, topological irreducibility implies algebraic irreducibility, so the two notions are the same. But in the group representation case, they rarely coincide.

Comment: I've presented a more verbose version of Johannes Ebert's answer in math.SE (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4140600/52543) for the purpose of that audience, while also trying to address the multiple points discussed in the comments here and there.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: @MasayoshiKaneda Thank you indeed for your valuable comment. If we postulate that the intertwiner $M$ is bounded, will it warrant that ${\cal{Im}}\, M$ is closed?

Comment: @Michael_1812: Actually, "continuous=bounded" for linear operators, and I was talking about a general situation. Here, however, $M$ is an "intertwiner," so with this extra intertwining condition, one can prove that $\mathcal{Im}M$ is closed as Johannes Ebert and Pedro Lauridsen Ribeiro have already provided excellent full answers.

Comment: @MasayoshiKaneda, thank you for this comment. Will think it over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $V$ and $W$ be Hilbert spaces with irreducible unitary $G$-actions and let $T:V \to W$ be a bounded intertwiner. Then the adjoint is an intertwiner as well and hence so are $T^\ast T$ and $TT^\ast$. Claim: These two are multiples of the identity. It follows that $T$ is zero or a multiple of an isometric isomorphism.

To prove the claim, it is enough to show that a selfadjoint intertwiner $A$ of an irreducible represenation is a multiple of the identity.

But the spectral projections of $A$ are intertwiners. By irreducibility, they are either 0 or 1. The spectrsl theorem then proves that $A$ is a multiple of the identity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This classical result that the intertwiner $T$ is either zero or a multiple of identity  is actually valid only for dimensions less than continuum. In 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336559/dixmiers-lemma-as-a-generalisation-of-schurs-first-lemma/336623#336623 , this is proven by a counterexample.  (Please scroll to the bottom of that discussion.)

Comment: Also, your answer does not address the question asked. To prove Schur's lemma, is it sufficient to demonstrate the invariance of $\,{\cal{Im}} \,M\,$ and $\,{\cal{Ker}} \,M\,$, or is it necessary to prove the invariance of their closures? (And if the closures, then what additional assumptions should be made about the representations and/or the intertwiner?)

Comment: Finally, can we avoid requiring the representations to be unitary?

Comment: The counterexample is based on the fact that the complex numbers have a nontrivial field extension (of uncountable dimension). Since no Banach algebra except C is a skewfield (Gelfand-Mazur), such problems do not appear if you impose a completeness hypothesis.

Comment: The argument assumed that T is bounded. In that case, it follows that im(T) is closed.

Comment: Unitarity is needed to guarantee that the adjoint is an intertwiner.

Comment: Johannes, your comment on the boundedness of T as a warrant of Im T being closed is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you for this. Can you kindly explain how the boundedness entails the closedness? (A physicist, and need help with things that may look simple to a mathematician.)

Comment: I also failed to understand your comment of the counterexample. Based on a fact that you cited, and not on a hypothesis, the counterexample is valid, is it not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124296/discussion-between-johannes-ebert-and-michael-1812).

Comment: With pleasure..